# Requirejs do not add ".js" for modules using karma

Tags: requirejs, typescript, karma-runner, webstorm, karma-jasmine

I have simple test, that must work in webstorm using karma and requirejs.

The problem is that for some reason requirejs do not add ".js" for modules i was loading for tests. So it crashed trying to load "../ts/mamats/mama", while "../ts/mamats/mama.js" exists

Test (main.jasmine.js):

```
define(["require", "exports", "../ts/mamats/mama"], function(require, exports, mama) {
    describe("first test", function () {
        it("should be true", function () {
            var object = new mama.block();
            expect(object instanceof mama.block).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
//# sourceMappingURL=main.jasmine.js.map
```

every thing works correctly when i replace "../ts/mamats/mama" with "../ts/mamats/mama.js"

sourceMappingURL here because javaScript file generated from typeScript source file, and because of that i cannot add ".js" for modules manually

Test starts with this entry point (main-test.js):

```
var tests = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).filter(function (file) {
    return (/\.jasmine\.js$/).test(file);
});
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/base',
    deps: tests,
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

Why requirejs don't add ".js" for modules here?

Karma conf file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '../',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
    files: [
      'static-tests/main-test.js',
      { pattern: 'static/**/*', included: false },
      { pattern: 'static-tests/**/*', included: false }
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: Looks like solution is here: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-requirejs/issues/3

will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like trouble in require.js

The problem is in next:
 1. When in deps appear absolute path - requirejs stop add ".js" for any require call
 2. When in deps appear file with extension, for some reason requirejs again stop add ".js" for modules

Other Solution here - to replace bathUrl and add it to requirejs conf do not help.

For me solution is next:

```
var tests = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).filter(function (file) {
    return (/\-jasmine\.js$/).test(file);
}).map(function (file) {
    return file.replace(/^\/|\.js$/g, '');
});
```

and

```
baseUrl: '',
```

for requirejs.conf

and i have no idea why requirejs still add "/base" for all url that are requested, but now all works fine

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting read on how RequireJs handles this:

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

Reading that makes it seem like an issue with RequireJS, but there seems to be some debate on whether or not that is true. Regardless, this [gist](https://gist.github.com/thomassuckow/6372324) seems to solve the issue.

```
var tests = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).filter(function (file) {
  return /\.spec\.js$/.test(file);
}).map(function(file){
  return file.replace(/^\/base\/src\/js\/|\.js$/g,'');
});

require.config({
  baseUrl: '/base/src/js'
});

require(tests, function(){
  window.__karma__.start();
});
```